# NullPointerException at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger

Tags: java, logging

After upgrading from Java 6 to Java 8, my application throws the following exception:

```
com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: Java exception occurred: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:451)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclFeval(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.access$600(MWMCR.java:23)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$6.mclFeval(MWMCR.java:833)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$5.invoke(MWMCR.java:731)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.mclFeval(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.invoke(MWMCR.java:406)
    at mDataEngine.mDataEngineMIF.volatility(mDataEngineMIF.java:7212)
```

This occurs when using the mathworks library, which in turn uses java.util.logging.Logger where the exception is thrown.

Comment: What is the exact version of Java 8 that you are using?

Comment: `java version "1.8.0_25"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)`

Comment: Does the same error happen on java version "1.8.0_66"?  If so I can submit a bug report to Oracle.

Comment: I could test it with version 1.8.0_65-b17 and the error DOES occur here, so it's very likely that it will also occur in 66. I hope this information is sufficient for you.

Comment: Here is the link to the Oracle bug [JDK-8145302 NullPointerException at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145302)

Comment: If you launch this with '-Xint' to disable hotspot does the same NPE occur?  Do you know of an isolated test case that I could run to reproduce this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Oracle bug JDK-8145302 NullPointerException at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145302) has been replaced with

[JDK-8177325 Caller sensitive methods Logger.getLogger, Logger.getAnonymousLogger, will throw NPE if there is no caller on the stack.](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177325)

The workaround in that bug report is listed as:

> Workaround: use an auxiliary class in order to call Logger.getLogger instead of calling Logger::getLogger directly from JNI.

As you can see from your stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:451)
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclFeval(Native Method) 
...
```

the `com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclFeval` is a JNI method calling `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger`.

Mathworks should update the `MWMCR` class to include a java helper method to invoke `getLogger` and that helper method should be called from JNI instead of `getLogger` directly.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by setting the following system property when starting the Java program:

```
-Dsun.util.logging.disableCallerCheck=true
```

More detailed information:

The reason for the NullpointerException seems to be explained here: http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/07/Oracle-Removes-getCallerClass

The method getCallerClass is used here in java.util.logging.Logger:

```
 public static Logger More ...getLogger(String name) {
     return demandLogger(name, null, Reflection.getCallerClass());
 }
```

This leads to the variable caller to be null in the following code of java.util.logging.Logger:

```
     if (sm != null && !SystemLoggerHelper.disableCallerCheck) {
         if (caller.getClassLoader() == null) {
             return manager.demandSystemLogger(name, resourceBundleName);
         }
     }
     return manager.demandLogger(name, resourceBundleName, caller);
```

By setting the systemvariable as explained above, the caller variable will not be used.